# How to Check if the Elements appear in the while loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to crawl data, the site has some stricky tricks to hide the data so I have to do a while loop (click 2 buttons continuous until the data appears in DOM, and actual visible).

But I got trouble here, I can't check if the data is appeare and stop the loop.

This is the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const iPhone = puppeteer.devices['iPhone X'];

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulate(iPhone);

    await page.goto('https://website.com/abcXyZ/');

    // countData is the number of the ul>li. When nothing show, its value is 0. When appeared, value is >0
    const countData = await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByClassName('js-list')[0].getElementsByTagName('li').length)

    while (countData < 1) {
        await page.click('.btn1')
        await page.waitForTimeout(600)
        await page.click('.bt2')
        await page.waitForTimeout(600)

        const isFound = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.contains(document.querySelector('.goWork')))
        if (isFound) break
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

The loop run only once and stop. I want to click 2 btns until the data appear and stop the loop. How can I fix this code?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of easier of ways doing this but that is not your question. To be able to say where is the problem in your code we need to see the webpage source code. So without it i am going to make a guess.

```
const isFound = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.contains(document.querySelector('.goWork')))
if (isFound) break
```

Your code above checks the body of the page contains an element with a class named `goWork`. If the body contains it you break the loop. So that might be the problem. It looks like the body contains an element with `goWork` class.

Comment: And can you give me solutions to make it simplier, my code seems complicated. The website URL I want to crawl is https://v.douyin.com/Jts3CQf/. You have to visit it as mobile device, and incase you don't see data, you need to click the buttons (yellow one) continuous until the data appears.

Comment: You can use puppeteer's `waitForSelector` method. Check this link https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options

Comment: waitForSelector will make the loop stop and wait, it doesn't work for me in this case. I have a question, if I use http get request/fetch method instead, will it works as clicking button?

Comment: Of course `waitForSelector` will make the loop stop and wait. That is what it is doing. You need to change your code to work with it. If you trying to click a link and get the data from that URL you can simply fetch it yourself without clicking it. It will return you that URLs source code.You can try it yourself and see the result. If you want to navigate to that URL you can simply use `await page.goto(url)`